# ¿Puede alguien explicarme las diferencias entre HttpResponse y HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: python, django

No estoy entendiendo las diferencias entre `HttpResponse` y `HttpResponseRedirect`.

**¿Podría alguien explicarme?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase `HttpResponseRedirect` es una subclase de `HttpResponseRedirect` diseñada para simplificar el trabajo de enviar una redireccción a otra página web en lugar de enviar datos.

Segun el protocolo HTTP existen diferentes estados de respuestas:  [Estados HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)

- El estado 200 significa que todo está bien y envia informacion al cliente (ej.: navegador web) para que la procese (ej.: mostrar página).
- El estado 302 significa que la página or recurso que se esta solicitado se encuentra en temporalmente otro lugar y envia una dirección con la nueva ubicación, el cliente (navegador web) toma esa dirección y se dirige a ella.

En resumen:

`HttpResponse`: Es la classe que se encarga de enviar informacion de diferente tipo al cliente.
`HttpResponseRedirect`: Es una subclase que solo sirve para enviar direcciones url al las que el cliente redirecciona.